# How to send a segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, navigationbar

i have a button on which when i click it take me to the next screen, the name of the navigation bar is "Main" for the first screen, i want that when i navigate to the next screen it should show me that title instead of "back" button, so far i am unable to get the result as it is throwing me the exception, kindly help me , my code is as follows.

```
-(IBAction)btnMore:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"more" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSString*)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"more"])
    {
        moreInfo *vc = (moreInfo*)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.str = (NSString*)sender;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception you are getting? any msg?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should simply do as follow :-

//Set title of your Main and second View using IB

[image: Set title of your Main and second View using IB]

Then it would automatically change back title to the given one like below.

//Back title is replaced with "Main" title of main VC

[image: Back title is replaced with "Main" title of main VC]

Comment: Please whoever is voting down ,do provide the reason in comments as it helps in improving the answer along with knowledge sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like part of your problem may be that your sender is probably a view controller, so casting a view controller to a NSString* doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this;

Easy way...
create local variable to the class like this.

```
@interface Main() {
    NSString *titleOfSecView;
}

-(IBAction)btnMore:(UIButton *)sender
{
    titleOfSecView = sender.titleLabel.text;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"more" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSString*)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"more"])
    {
        moreInfo *vc = (moreInfo*)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.str = titleOfSecView;
    }
}
```